# upload files and post them at the end of a process

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, kendo-ui

I all,
I'm wrting a wizard in angularJs, the base idea is to post the data to the server only at the final step of the wizard. 
During the steps data is being saved in context object at client side.
The user needs to use three different files, in three different fields at the second step, and at the fifth (final) step, when user clicks on the Finish button I need to post the selected files from the second step to ther server.

Is it possible?
* The input for the select file is kendo ui

Thank you in advanced

Comment: Have you checked ng-flow module to achieve this, ng-flow supports for multiple file uploads, you can customize it for your needs. https://github.com/DmitryEfimenko/FlowJs-MVC

Comment: Hi thank you I reviewed the ng-flow but still could not find how to save the files during the wizard steps and post them to the server at the end, (the submit is happening at the end)

Comment: And another issue is that at the same time when I post to the server I need to post the files and another data, thank you again

Comment: There are some events in the ng-flow which you can check and keep state until you get the final wizard and post data in that step. You could try that, but ng-flow no work on ie 9 or below versions.